# Setting the minimum value of field based on another field in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have a `start` and `stop` field in my form and I wish to have the user enter a `start` field then enter the `stop` field, however, the minimum value for the `stop` field needs to be the `start` field's value. Is there any way to achieve this?

my view:

```
    <div class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;">
                    <label for="recipient-name" style="width: 7em"class="col-form-label">Start</label>
                    <input type="number"style="width: 7em" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" min="0" required>

 <div class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;">
                    <label for="recipient-name" style="width: 7em"class="col-form-label">Stop</label>
                    <input type="number"style="width: 7em" name="stop" class="form-control" id="stop" min="0" required>
              
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using an `onchange` handler:

```
<div class="mb-3" style="float:left;" style="margin-left: 200px;">
                    <label for="recipient-name" style="width: 7em"class="col-form-label">Start</label>
                    <input type="number"style="width: 7em" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" min="0" onchange="document.getElementById('stop').min=this.value;" required>
                  </div>
                
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">End ODO</label>
                    <input type="number" style="width: 7em" name="stop" class="form-control @error('stop') is-invalid @enderror" id="stop" min="document.getElementById('start').value"  value="{{ old('stop') }}" required>
                    @error('end_odo')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
               
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple jQuery method:

```
Add `disabled` attribute in your stop input Html

<input type="number"style="width: 7em" name="stop" class="form-control" 
disabled id="stop" min="0" required>
```

then using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('blur','#start',function(){
 //make stop input disabled false after focus out from start input
    $("#stop").prop("disabled",false);
//set stop input minimum value to start value
    $("#stop").attr("min",$("#start").val());
    $("#stop").val($("#start").val());
});
```